# Pass variable to view via controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I need help with passing the variable I have initialized using `__construct()` to view in Laravel.

Here is my controller code

```
protected $profileInfo;

public function __construct(){
   $this->profileInfo = Profile::with('address')->where('id', '=', '1')->get();
}
public function index(){
  $this->profileInfo;
  return view('admin_pages.profile', compact('profileInfo'));
}
```

I get an error `undefined variable profileInfo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `compact()` the parameters used must be defined as variables:

```
protected $profileInfo;

public function __construct(){
   $this->profileInfo = Profile::with('address')->where('id', '=', '1')->get();
}
public function index(){
  $profileInfo = $this->profileInfo;
  return view('admin_pages.profile', compact('profileInfo'));
}
```

In this case `compact()` will create an array like this:

```
[ 'profileInfo' => $this->profileInfo ]
```

Answer (score 1):

`compact()` looks for a variable with that name in the current symbol table and adds it to the output array such that the variable name becomes the key and the contents of the variable become the value for that key.

Instead of using `compact` you can pass an array like this:

```
protected $profileInfo;

public function __construct(){
   $this->profileInfo = Profile::with('address')->where('id', '=', '1')->get();
}

public function index(){
  return view('admin_pages.profile', ['profileInfo' => $this->profileInfo]);
}
```

Comment: Always explain your answer instead of just saying "Try this".

Comment: @GertB. You are right. I've edited my answer.